# How to make bootable pendrive without any additional software

Tags: 21.04

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask because my question is related to both Ubuntu and Windows but also overall about computer and systems. I hope it won't be any problem if I ask here.

Through the years I was trying many different tutorials on how to make a bootable pendrive with a system but without any additional software and some of them was even telling me that I can just copy and paste the files into pendrive but as you can expect it wasn't working. Some was using a terminal or console commands but I always ended up with an error or not bootable pendrive.

So, could someone experienced explain it to me how to make a bootable pendrive without any additional software? (On Ubuntu 21.04 and on Windows 10 if possible) Also as an additional question could anyone tell me why Ubuntu 21.04 is not LTS version like every year .04 is?

Comment: Every *even* years the April release is LTS (18.04, 20.04 and future 22.04), any other release isn't. For UEFI systems you can just extract the ISO files into a FAT32 formatted USB stick (if doing it from the current Windows ISO use NTFS instead). For old BIOS I don't know and I don't care.

Comment: The POSIX `dd` command will write the ISO to thumb-drive; it's often avoided as it'll write from file to file, or file to device meaning everything on the device being written to is lost... (ie. no safety checks; why we use USB writing software that performs checks before it writes).   But note: there are multiple types of ISO files and not all get written the same way, so how it's written will depend on type of ISO, so a blanket command should not be expected to write.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Technically it's the first release (not including re-spins or point releases) on an even year; in 2006 the first release was June thus 6.06 LTS, however Canonical/Ubuntu have worked hard ever since at keeping releases in April & October so releases since 2007 have always been in April (.04) meaning LTS releases since 6.06 where 8.04, 10.04, 12.04, 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04

Comment: There are 3 ways to create a bootable Ubuntu USB using only the software that comes with Ubuntu: 1) Startup Disk Creator. 2) Gnome-Disks. 3) dd.

Comment: Are you trying to create a USB with a Live Environment (like the Live ISO you download from Ubuntu, but with less software) or are you trying to *install* Ubuntu onto an USB (as you would install Ubuntu onto your computer's disk, but with less software) ?

Answer (score 0):

try opening Ubuntu 21.04, Disks, then select on the left, the USB PEN, then select the first partition, then Shift+F10, choose Edit Partition, click Bootable, and then OK/change... Reboot to choose PEN in old BIOS.